# Convert images to PNG after reading media item from Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, png, sitecore, converters

This is code that i have now implemented:

```cs
string image = String.Empty;
ImageField imageField = itm.Fields["image"];

MediaItem mediaItem = imageField.MediaItem;

if (mediaItem != null)
{
     Stream stream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();

     Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, 188, 122);

     ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

     Byte[] bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
     stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     image = "data:" + mediaItem.MimeType + "," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

 }

 return image;
```

What i would like to do is to convert all images that come through, into PNGs. The problem that i have right now, is that GIF images that i read from Sitecore, after all the conversion that you see above, render as black images.

I tried some implementations but the result seems to be the same.

Could anyone please help?

Best regards, Marius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the actual problem was that i had an additional line of code that was messing things up, and i am talking about this one: `stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

This my final code that is currently working:

```cs
string image = String.Empty;
ImageField imageField = itm.Fields["image"];

MediaItem mediaItem = imageField.MediaItem;

if (mediaItem != null)
{
    Stream stream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();

    Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, 188, 122);

    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

    Stream pngStream = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.Save(pngStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    Byte[] bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(Image.FromStream(pngStream), typeof(byte[]));
    image = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
return image;
```

I hope that it's helpful for somebody.

Have a great day.

Comment: Awesome! Since this is the correct answer, I would delete my answer. Thanks.